# How to achieve batching in spring resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi i have been searching about this but could not get perfect answer.I have following code snippet

```
 SparkResponse<CommonEvents> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<SparkResponse<CommonEvents>>() { }).getBody();
```

How can i achieve batching in resttemplate?

I tried using ResponseExtractor but it didnot work for me.

batching is needed as at times the data volumn is too high and i get heap memory exception. Please let me know if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this can help. But I guess, you can give this a try.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use async operations in order to get the response batched.
Note that Spring 5, which has reactive web functionality, comes with `WebClient`, which can convert response to `Flux`, that can be batched.
Example code:

```
WebClient.create(url)
            .method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .body(entity, Object.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(SparkResponse.class)
            .buffer(20)
```

And then you can go from there.
Hope this helps =)

Comment: Hi DruidKuma WebFlux requires springboot version 2.X.X and above and am not allowed to change the spring boot version

Comment: Could you please tell what version are you using?